# How can I draw an etched 3D line on a WinForm?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Please refer to the following image:

[image]

I wanted to group the controls like that. Beside Email, Calendar, and Tasks, there's a line drawn. I searched, but I don't think I got anywhere close to finding the solution. They all point to drawing using GDI, whatever that is. Even fiddled with the group box with no use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this control? Group Box or Not!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897584/what-is-this-control-group-box-or-not) It's a `STATIC` control; my answer gives full sample code for creating the exact same control in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you very close:

```
label1.AutoSize = false;
label1.Height = 2;
label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to tinker with the position though.

Answer (score 3):

That separator can be achieved by creating a [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) that has a height of 2 pixels and has the `BorderStyle` property set to `Fixed3D`.

Comment: Awww. Snap, you were quick :)

Comment: Alse the `AutoSize` property should be set to `false`, @pirho 's answer should be upvoted as it contains the full description.